# Where do I upload p12 file received from Google Analytics to Pentaho Server?

Tags: google-analytics, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho community version and using PDI on my local machine. I am trying to integrate PDI with Google Analytics and I am able to do so with my local machine. But when I put the same transformation file on to the server (PUC upload), It is unable to access the .p12 credential file generated by Google Analytics. The only way this seems possible if I upload the credential file on some server location which is accessible to my Pentaho Server.

How to solve this? Where should I put the credential file on the server for this to work? Is this functionality even available in Pentaho Community Version?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isnt Pentaho  support.  OP should contact Pentaho

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep the file in the server for sure, use a variable to store the key file path and use the variable in that place, this variable should be from kettle properties. Set your variable according to your environment needs. The key is variable pointing to the variable path which is obtained from kettle properties.